# Python not recognizing Unicode in a text file

Tags: python-2.7

I tried to read a log file which has Unicode texts, but couldn't print encoded strings which are Korean words. I would know What was wrong?

The codes are as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import yaml

path = "./mylog.log"
mylog = open( path, "r")
for i in mylog:
    message = i.split("app[web.1]:")[1]
    message = yaml.load(message)  # text -> dict
    print message
    mytext = message["u'content'"]
    print mytext.encode('utf-8')
    print isinstance(mytext, unicode)
```

The results of the codes are as below:

```
{"u'content'": "u'\\uc131\\uacfc'", "u'type'": "u'text'", "u'user_key'": "u'ADAgPNQ04'"}

u'\uc131\uacfc'
```

False

```
{"u'content'": "u'\\uc131\\uacfc'", "u'type'": "u'text'", "u'user_key'": "u'ADAgPNQ04'"}

u'\uc131\uacfc
```

'
False

It seems that my text was not recognized as Unicode,

If I run similar codes in Python console, I got the correct result:

```
In[1]: text = u'\uc131\uacfc'   
In[2]: print text
```

성과     # a Korean word

mylog.log:

```
2016-11-22T07:35:30.197270+00:00 app[web.1]: {u'content': u'\uc131\uacfc', u'user_key': u'ADAgPNQ04', u'type': u'text'}

2016-11-22T09:55:09.994257+00:00 app[web.1]: {u'content': u'\uc131\uacfc', u'user_key': u'ADAgPNQ04', u'type': u'text'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It works well.

```
mylog = codecs.open(path,"r" ,encoding='utf-8')
for i in mylog:
    message = i.split("app[web.1]:")[1]
    message = message .decode('unicode_escape')
    mytext = yaml.load(message )  
    mytext = mytext["u'content'"]
    print mytext
```